# How to check something inside repeater control?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Is it possible to check something using If statement inside repeater control and decide which HTML statement to go through depends on If statement ? like this (C# code)

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
    ...
    if(something) do() .. else do_else()..
    ...
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Use the language of your choice and the codebehind, a good place is [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter But i need to use <%#Eval("..") %> inside the HTML code..?

Comment: You don't _need_ `Eval`.  In codebehind you have the [`DataItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.dataitem.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is as:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" >
<ItemTemplate>

<%if(something) {%> 
 write this
<%}else{%>
 write that
<%}%>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Similar:
[Format Data in an ASP.NET Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937425/format-data-in-an-asp-net-repeater/3937509#3937509)
[Want 10 rows in every page while binding to a repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122440/want-10-rows-in-every-page-while-binding-to-a-repeater/12122938#12122938)
[Can I use filter in asp:repeater?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196364/can-i-use-filter-in-asprepeater/14196521#14196521)